# Changing WPF databindings based on value of another property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm reasonably new to WPF, have developed a couple of apps with code-beinding files and have read up on MVVM (via Schifflett's 'in the box' introduction) prior to starting my current application.

The items I'm working with have a bunch of generic string properties, plus a Dictionary property called Hours which maps dates to hours worked.

My user interface has a DataGrid view of these items (bound to a collection in the ViewModel), and a combobox which allows the user to select a date (which binds the selected value to `SelectedDate` in the ViewModel). The DataGrid's Hours column needs to show the number of hours worked in the week (i.e., have the same effect as calling `item.Hours[SelectedDate]` or similar).

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to put a variable within the binding expression like `{Binding Hours[SelectedDate]}`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a datagrid that has a collection of dates and hours worked. And a combobox that lets you select the date. Why do you need both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two solutions that immediately come to mind are these:

1) Create an Hours property that is based on your SelectedDate:

```
public int Hours {get { return calculateHours(SelectedDate); } }
```

"calculateHours" could either be a method or you could put the calculation in the Setter itself.  Make sure that whenever SelectedDate is Set that you raise PropertyChanged for "Hours" as well.

I would use this approach if this Hours calculation is only used in this View from this ViewModel.

2) Create a Value Converter that accepts a date and returns the calculated value.  Then bind the Hours to the SelectedDate property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDate, Converter={StaticResource DateToHoursConverter}}"
```

I would use this approach if the calculation is required in multiple Views or in multiple ViewModels.  Value Converters are great for this kind of reuse.

Answer (score 0):

if your property you bind to has an indexer, you can bind to it. you just have to raise INotifyPropertyChanged for this indexer at the right time.

edit: a variable within the binding expression will not work, but you can bind to Hours and use a converter and the SelectedDate as convertparameter to get the value you want. you should have to raise INotifyPropertyChanged for "Hours" when "SeletedDate" changed.